# How to get length of Map object in Firestore database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 objects in a `document`, an empty `array` and a `map` object with 3 objects. If one is empty it becomes type `array` and I can `console.log(vehicles.Motorcycles.length)` and get `0`, if there is objects it becomes type `map` and when I `console.log(vehicles.Cars.length)` I get `undefined`.

How can I get the length of the `map` `object`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know that the complex, nested objects in a document are called maps.
The size of the map is calculated the same way as the document size,check [Field Value Size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size?hl=en-419#field-size).
The size of a document is the sum of:

- The document name size
- The sum of the string size of each field name
- The sum of the size of each field value
- 32 additional bytes

Meaning that you need to add those 32 additional bytes when you calculate the size of the content of a Map. As there is a Map name, which is calculated as the length of the name plus 1 byte. Check out the [Map Global Object Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) document

Try out the following :

`console.log(vehicles.Cars.size)`

Instead of

`console.log(vehicles.Cars.length)`